# Want spring integration amqp dsl example

Tags: spring-integration, amqp, dsl, spring-amqp

I want to found some spring integration amqp dsl examples , as a newer, someone can give me a complete detailed examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html) there are Java DSL configuration examples for each AMQP component.

[image: ToC]

Comment: sorry, I can not understand the concepts of  inbound , outbound and gateway completely, and can not write the examples according the above document . Is there DSL examples like ( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/amqp )

Comment: There's lots of explanation of those concepts in earlier chapters. I suggest you read those. If you have a _specific_ question after doing that, edit your question.